# How to reduce the nested foreaches for a 5-levels deep array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, tree-traversal

I have a PHP tree structure (array max depth: 5):

```
$arr = array(
    '31' => array(
        'Amsterdam' => array(),
        'Rotterdam' => array(),
        'Den Haag' => array(),
        'Utrecht' => array(),
        'Eindhoven' => array(),
        'Tilburg' => array(),
        'Almere' => array(
            '036' => array(
                'BU00340212' => array(
                    'name' => 'Muziekwijk Noord',
                    'residents' => array(
                        'Henk',
                        'Dirk',
                        'Jaap',
                    ),
                ),
                'BU00340213' => array(
                    'name' => 'Muziekwijk Zuid',
                    'residents' => array(
                        'Wim',
                        'Pim',
                        'Jim',
                        'Tim',
                    ),
                ),
            )
        ),
        'Groningen' => array(),
        'Breda' => array(),
        'Nijmegen' => array(),
    )
);
```

I would like to have this output:

```
Almere(netnummer: 036)(cbscode: BU00340212): Henk
Almere(netnummer: 036)(cbscode: BU00340212): Dirk
Almere(netnummer: 036)(cbscode: BU00340212): Jaap
Almere(netnummer: 036)(cbscode: BU00340213): Wim
Almere(netnummer: 036)(cbscode: BU00340213): Pim
Almere(netnummer: 036)(cbscode: BU00340213): Jim
Almere(netnummer: 036)(cbscode: BU00340213): Tim
```

So I did some coding by myself. The code below produces the output that I want.

```
foreach($arr as $unitKey => $citySet){

    foreach($citySet as $cityName => $cityData){

        if($cityName === 'Almere'){

            $almere = $citySet[$cityName];

            foreach($almere as $netnummer => $netData){

                foreach($netData as $cbsCode => $data){

                    foreach($data['residents'] as $residents){
                        echo $cityName . '(netnummer: '. $netnummer .')(cbscode: '. $cbsCode .'): ' . $residents . '<br>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code displayed above makes use of 5 foreaches, and I'm doubting if that's a good idea. So I tried to reduce a couple foreaches like this:

```
$arrB = $arr['31']['Almere']['036'];
foreach($arrB as $k => $netData){
    foreach($netData as $field => $fieldData){
        if($field === 'residents') {
            foreach($fieldData as $resident){
                echo 'Almere(netnummer: 036)(cbscode: '. $k .'): ' . $resident . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code displayed above makes use of 3 foreaches. That is because it doesn't traverse the full tree.

I want to traverse the full tree with 1 foreach, and produce the output I was aiming for. So I was thinking about RecursiveArray in combination with RecursiveIteratorIterator, but I can't get the cbscode if I use this approach. See for yourself:

```
$recursiveArrayIterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr);
$recursiveIteratorIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursiveArrayIterator);
foreach($recursiveIteratorIterator as $k => $v){
    if($k !== 'name'){
        echo 'Almere(netnummer: 036)(cbscode: ???): ' . $v . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Q1: is this possible to traverse the tree structure with one foreach with the shown output?

Q2:if it is possible, can you show the code? if not, is it possible to reduce the amount of used foreaches to 2?

-- Edit --

Q (rephrased): What is most readable way to fully traverse an 5 level deep array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I invested some time in this problem, and came with a functional programming approach:

```
function recursive($data, $countryCode = null, $countryData = null, $city = null, $cityData = null, $netNummer = null, $netData = null, $cbscode = null, $cbsData = null, $residents = null){

    if($residents){
        $resident = array_shift($residents);
        echo $city . '(netnummer: ' . $netNummer . ')(cbscode: ' . $cbscode .'): ' . $resident . '<br>';

        if($residents){
            recursive($data, $countryCode, $countryData, $city, $cityData, $netNummer, $netData, $cbscode, $cbsData, $residents);
        }

        return null;
    }

    if($cbscode && $cbsData){
        $residents = $cbsData['residents'];
        recursive($data, $countryCode, $countryData, $city, $cityData, $netNummer, $netData, $cbscode, $cbsData, $residents);
    }

    if($countryCode && $countryData && $netData){
        $cbscode = key($netData);
        $cbsData = array_shift($netData);
        recursive($data, $countryCode, $countryData, $city, $cityData, $netNummer, $netData, $cbscode, $cbsData);
    }

    if($countryCode && $countryData && $city && $cityData){
        $netNummer = key($cityData);
        $netData = array_shift($cityData);
        recursive($data, $countryCode, $countryData, $city, $cityData, $netNummer, $netData);
    }

    if($countryCode && $countryData){
        $city = key($countryData);
        $cityData = array_shift($countryData);
        recursive($data, $countryCode, $countryData, $city, $cityData);
    }

    if($data){
        $countryCode = key($data);
        $countryData = array_shift($data);
        if($countryData){
            recursive($data, $countryCode, $countryData);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

recursive($arr);
```

Online source: https://3v4l.org/rsf5o

Answer (score 3):

You can short this down to:

```
$arrB = $arr['31']['Almere']['036'];
foreach($arrB as $code => $val) {
    if (isset($val["residents"])) {
        $prefix = 'Almere(netnummer: 036)(cbscode: '. $code .'): ';
        echo $prefix . implode('<br>' . $prefix, $val["residents"]) . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/1JLr2)

Comment: That's a clever trick :-) I just didn't thought about `implode`.

Comment: What is your opinion about this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56076382/1280520 ?

Comment: I think it is too complicate for recursion - it may works by I believe `foreach` is more suitable

Comment: I agree with you that it is complicated, but the functional approach has one advantage over the `foreach`, which is that it retrieves `Almere(netnummer: 036)(cbscode: BU00340212)` by the algorithm instead of a hard-coded manner. The functional approach traverses the whole datastructure, which is favorable in my situation. Anyway, the job of the programmer is to take a look at possible solutions with their pro's and con's, and then to make a well considered choice.

Comment: @Julian It is up to you to decide what to use - my opinion is the `foreach` better here. I prefer adding 2 more loop then to use the recursion approach here as the behavior in each step of the recursion are different. Which answer is correct? up to you but I do think I answer the original question of "How to reduce the nested foreach loops"

Comment: You are 100% right, thanks for your input. Sometimes I ask a question because I want to achieve something, so I phrase my question in a specific way, but after some time I realize that there are other ways (maybe a better) of achieving a specific goal. The original question is: "How to reduce the nested foreach loops", but I should ask: `What is most readable way to fully traverse an 5 level deep array?`.